# Button for outlook using the newsletter

Tags: html, newsletter

I am developing an email marketing and I am using the newsletter.

One of the problems I encountered in the development was that the style of my buttons worked in gmail, but in outlook it does not work.
[image: screenshot]
The style of my buttons:

```html
<a href="http://www.piccolohotelastoria.com/ponte_2_giugno_dal_1_6_al_5_6.php"
style="text-decoration:none;
background-color:rgb(243, 243, 243);
background-color:-webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(243, 243, 243), rgb(1, 1, 223));
background:linear-gradient(rgb(243, 243, 243), rgb(1, 1, 223));
border-radius:25px;
box-shadow:1px 1px rgb(1, 1, 188);
padding:10px 20px;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-weight:bold;
font-size:17px;">
VEDI  OFFERTA
</a>
```

Can anyone tell me how I can style the buttons in Outlook?

Comment: Please specify what exactly do you mean by "does not work".

Comment: I forgot my image

Comment: pulled image into question and formatted HTML to ease reading

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, compared to the web, a lot more code is required to get a button looking right in email clients. *Especially Outlook*.

Here is some sample code that should display fairly consistently:

```
<div>
    <!--[if mso]>
      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1e3650" fill="t">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/0xPEf.gif" color="#556270" />
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">VDDI OFFERTA</center>
      </v:roundrect>
    <![endif]-->
    <a href="http://www.piccolohotelastoria.com/ponte_2_giugno_dal_1_6_al_5_6.php"
style="background-color:#556270;background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/0xPEf.gif);border:1px solid #1e3650;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">VDDI OFFERTA</a>
</div>
```

Everything within the `<!--[if mso]>` tags is for Windows Desktop 2007 and above. And an image needs to be created for the effect to appear in Outlook (CSS `-linear-gradient` is not supported).